# Implementing cryptobiosis into larger animals

Tags: science-based, biochemistry

We live in a game, called *TierZoo*, the game sports incredible graphics and hundreds upon thousands of active and passive skills. One of the most powerful and coveted abilities is [Cryptobiosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptobiosis), especially Anoxybiosis. The ability to suspend yourself for as long as you want? Who doesn't want that?! Even if you have a total circulatory collapse, your brain can survive for years, at least, that'd be the case if I actually managed to implement the ability into more complex animals.

Only a handful of creatures managed to actually unlock Cryptobiosis, humans aren't one of them. I want that to change. <s>And not</s> just to make my medical petrification work.

**So, could Anoxybiosis be implemented into humans, and if yes, how?**

Comment: can it be yes, with enough genetic engineering there is nothing particularly incompatible with the process, how, would be worth a Nobel prize at minimum.

Comment: Have a glance at the physiological processes of the [Crucian Carp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crucian_carp#Physiology) (they get drunk in the process, depressing their CNS), there are amphibians that can do it too, but with different mechanisms. You just need to define a viable metabolic pathway or oxygen reserve somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any cordate which can undergo Anoxybiosis. Invertebrates are particularly suited for cryptobiosis since their interiors have extra protection from the environment due to their structure supporting outer shell. In-spite of this, I believe there is only one or two cases of arthropods being able to undergo anoxybiosis and only in the larva stage. Nearly all other cases of anoxybiosis involve microorganisms.

From the literature it appears that celluar damage, particularly to membranes is mitigated by a large production of disaccharides, particularly Trehalose, which then interacts with the organisms cellular membranes as it desiccates. When the organism is exposed to sufficient water again, it revives. Particularly important to these processes is a seriously reduced metabolic state and favored anaerobic metabolic pathways.

From these basic facets of anoxybiosis, we can infer what it might look like in humans (although the ones undergoing this procedure would doubtless look anything but). For one, the interior would need extra protection from the envirorment to prevent damage to organs, as well as the neurological and circulatory pathways. A possible solution might be a mechanism for the secretion of an agent from the skin which forms a hard waxy layer completely covering the body (a sort of cocoon). Simultaneously, the cells would need to quickly produce some equivalent to large productions of disaccharides which would necessitate a large food intake and perhaps converting fat reserves to glucose as well as a desiccating process; in which most of the water from the human body is expelled (which is a large percentage by weight). What would be left would be a shrived grotesque mass.

Of course there are many biochemical problems and issues with this, which is probably why the process has never been observed in most organisms, but if it could occur this is probably what it would look like.